# If $A$ Is an Upper Triangle Matrix, the Adjoint Is Also Upper Triangular

Tags: linear-algebra, alternative-proof

I already proved it, but it was really laborious.  I am wondering if any one has a shorter proof?

Write $A = [a_{ik}]$ and let $\overline{A}_{rs} = [c_{ik}]$ denote the minor with row $r$ and column $s$ removed.  Then, we have:
$$c_{ik} = \begin{cases}
\, a_{ik} & i < r, k < s \\
\, a_{i(k+1)} \, \, \, \text{ when } & i < r, s \le k \\
\, a_{(i+1)k} & r \le i, k < s \\
\, a_{(i+1)(k+1)} & r \le i, s \le k
\end{cases}$$
Suppose that $\overline{A}_{rs}$ is not upper triangular $\rightarrow c_{ik} \ne 0$ with $i > k$.  Clearly, this is not possible in the first, third, and fourth case.  In the case with $i < r, s \le k$, $a_{i(k+1)} \ne 0$.  Since $i > k$ and $A$ is upper triangular, $a_{i(k+1)} = a_{ii}$.  This proves that if $c_{ik}$ is nonzero, $k = i - 1$.  Furthermore:
$$s \le k = i - 1 < i < r$$
Now, take a minor $\overline{A}_{rs}$ with $r < s$.  Suppose that it is not upper triangular; $c_{ik} \ne 0$ for some $i > k \rightarrow s \le i -1 < i < r$, a contradiction.  Moreover, $c_{rr} = a_{(r+1)r} = 0$.  Hence, $\overline{A}_{rs}$ is upper triangular with at least one zero in its diagonal entries.  The cofactor $(-1)^{r+s} \det \overline{A}_{rs} = 0$.

$\Gamma$, the matrix made up of the cofactors of $A$ is a lower triangular.  It follows that $\text{Adj } A = \Gamma^t$ is upper triangular.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $(e_1,...,e_n)$ is the orthogonal base. $A$ is upper triangular means $<A(e_i),e_j) =0$, $j>i$. This is equivalent to $<e_i,A^*(e_j)>=0$ $j>i$ so $A^*$ is lower triangular.